# How to Optimize this Active Record Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Sidekiq job tha triggers a sequence of active record  queries dependig a given format as you can see in the switch case statement.

**What is expected ?**

Fetch correctly all the data, it's the expected behavior and it's working correctly at the moment.

**What is the end goal?**

Optimize the queries loading everything with one sigle query instead of have 5.

```
Class FooService
      attr_reader :foo_format

  def initialize(foo_format)
    @foo_format = foo_format
  end

  def format_for(format)
    case format
    when foo::fooBarONE
      one
    when foo::fooBarTWO
      half
    when foo::fooBarThree
      third
    when foo::fooBarFour
      quarter
    when foo::fooBarFive
      format_1000er_format
    end
  end

  def one
    foo_format.where(form_key: 0, page_format: fooBarONE )
                      .order(format_price_query).first
  end

  def two
    foo_format.where(form_key: 3, page_format: fooBarTWO)
                      .order(format_price_query).first
  end

  def three
    foo_format.where(form_key: 3, page_format: fooBarThree)
                      .order(format_price_query).first
  end

  def four
    foo_format.where(form_key: 3, page_format: fooBarFour)
                      .order(format_price_query).first
  end

  def five
    foo_format.where(form_key: 7, page_format: fooBarFive)
                      .order(format_price_query).first
  end
```

This is the association in the model level

belongs_to :magazines_booking_unit,
foreign_key: :booking_unit_id,
class_name: 'Foo::Bar'

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to optimize this code without knowing what SQL queries it generates or even what the expected result is?

Answer (score 0):

May be like this (just pass arguments to this method)

```
def format_for(**args)
  foo_format
    .where(form_key: args[:form_key], page_format: args[:page_format])
    .order(format_price_query).first
end
```

Comment: I was thinking to use association to avoid having multiple sql calls in the background, using something like a join table on the fly or includes